# Hard time on learning Java EE - mostly installing and testing stuff

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, maven, spring-mvc

Its quite a while since I started learning Java EE (I come from Rails world).

I'd like to test create a simple blog to test these:
- Hibernate, JPA
- Spring with MVC
- JSF and routing
- Struts 2
- Eclipse and local test (modify, reload, check changes)
- Tomcat, Jboss or Jetty
- An administration area (Session)
- Maven

I've a basic knowledge of each of those but as soon as I spend tons of time installing stuff and, somehow, I manage to resolve all inconveniences there is ALWAYS something that goes wrong (installation, tutorial obsolete, should I work with Spring IDE, MyEclipse, Jboss Application Server or regular Eclipse?, tons of random errors, each tutorial asking for random dependencies, each showcase).

QUESTION
How do you create quickly a startup project with these components?
You go with some Maven archetype? If so which one?

What I'd like is something I can download or build equipped out of the box with all above mentioned components. To name a few:
- [railswizard.org](http://railswizard.org), [youvegotrails.com](http://youvegotrails.com), [railsboost.com/templates/new](http://railsboost.com/templates/new)

SIDE QUESTION
Currently I'm following this great series, can you suggest some more like this:
- http://www.youtube.com/user/koushks?feature=gb_p13n_ch_rec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'd like is something I can download or build equipped out of the box with all above mentioned components. To name a few:

http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home

Appfuse will take you through the initial setup of a maven built spring based web application with hibernate included.

If you come from the rails world you might also look into Spring Roo which tries to borrow from Ruby i'm told. The primary focus of roo is to stand up all of the technology you've listed above quickly.

Comment: Really interesting solutions! This is was a hopeless open question but I think these two will help me on this installing/testing trouble. After some time I'll need to know what mainstream uses, especially looks for in job interviews - unfortunately in Italy there's not much demand for rails developers :(

Comment: @AditSaxena Roo is pretty cool--but when something goes wrong it requires a pretty high-level knowledge of how it does its magic, in the context of the environment in which it does that magic. AppFuse is much less magical.

Answer (score 2):

*All* the above components in a single project? That makes no sense; Spring MVC, Struts 2, and JSF would rarely be combined in the same project.

Each web framework has demo applications, what's wrong with those? There are archetypes for at least some combinations, although I'm not sure it's not better to put them together yourself.

Without knowing what kind of issues/errors you're getting, it's impossible to help. Maven should be taking care of most/all dependency issues. You shouldn't be spending much time installing *anything* by hand except maybe an app container.

IMO you're better off asking specific, actionable questions, and start with each specific technology and build *up* an application, rather than trying to integrate everything at once--a sure recipe for frustration.

Comment: Understood, thank you. In fact I had the problem that it is very difficult for J2EE beginners understand which components one should begin with (and don't know which one I need without having a glimpse of each one): all I wanted is to run some code and understand if It has reasonable learning curve comparing to my other programming experience.

Comment: @AditSaxena Depends on what else you've done. Full-stack Java development has a fairly large learning curve, but it's largely understanding what's available, and how to glue it together. It also generates a different class of WTFs than Ruby/Rails; because much of it is static, it's generally easier to understand how something works/where something happens. The stuff that isn't generally has more eyes on it than Ruby/Rails libraries and *tends* to be more robust--but that's highly dependent on what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

For starting with a simple Java EE application, a good point to start is just downloading a Java EE 6 implementation.

Those are offered by various parties, which might be confusing at first. It's however just like there isn't the One and Only C compiler, but there are many and they all compile the same standard C.

For Java EE 6, obvious choices are GlassFish 3.1.2, JBoss AS 7.1, TomEE. (just pick one, at this stage it doesn't matter much which one you'll use).

Java EE 6 is a full stack solution. It's a single download and you don't necessarily need to install any other libraries. It comes with an MVC framework (JSF), an ORM solution (JPA), dependency injection (CDI), business logic support (EJB) and then some.

As for the IDE, NetBeans has a particular good default integration for GlassFish (can even be downloaded as one bundle), but for Eclipse it's not that difficult either. You need to download the Java EE edition of Eclipse and after starting it, go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace, search for "GlassFish" and install the "GlassFish Server Plugin".

See also [Minimal 3-tier Java EE app, without any XML config](http://jdevelopment.nl/minimal-3tier-java-ee-app-xml-config) for a very minimal example to get started and [JSF 2.0 tutorial with Eclipse and Glassfish](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html) for a very detailed one including instructions how to exactly setup the IDE.